# Site.xml with #!, still ok to have bare URL as home page?

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, ajax, xml-sitemap

I'm trying to get some ajax content on my main page indexed by google. I've implemented the #! url structure for that content and the corresponding piece on the server which renders what users see when passed the _escaped_fragment_ version of the urls. Ie, I followed the instructions here http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

I submitted the new site.xml to google 2 days ago through their webmaster tools. It's showing up as submitted URLs: 10, 1 URLs in index. So I'm assuming that something is wrong with my set up as the #! urls don't seem to be indexed.

This is a snippet of my site.xml

```
<url>
  <loc>http://www.mysite.com/</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.mysite.com/#!/Bristol</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.mysite.com/#!/Manchester</loc>
</url>
```

I don't want to just ask "What's wrong with this!?" so my best guess is I shouldn't be using the same url with and without the #! perhaps? or I need to put

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

in the page returned for those URLs? I didn't really follow what was being said on that bit of the instructions.

Comment: My suggest is to wait to jump to conclusions. 2 days is not always enough to let Google index again your website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That Sitemap file is fine. You don't need to specify the AJAX-crawling version of the URL there, but it generally will take a bit of time for these URLs to get crawled and indexed. A Sitemap file does not guarantee indexing, so in addition to just the Sitemap file, I'd also recommend doing the usual things that make sense when building & promoting a website, such as making sure that the pages are linked internally, so that the content can be crawled normally.

Comment: An HTML sitemap would be a good way to allow search engines to find the content so it "can be crawled normally."